# xCode 4.2, UIPickerView, Where is the File's Owner?

Tags: xcode4, uipickerview, xcode4.2

After some searching I know how to set the UIPickerView and its Content. The only problem is that i can't connect the UIPickerViews datasource and delegate Outlet to the File`s Owner because since 4.2 i can't find the File's Owner. Because of that, the Content isn't displayed on the UIPickerView.

Can anyone help me?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0EXa.png

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot of your Interface Builder UI? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came here looking for an answer to this but managed to find it on my own. Obvious once you know what to look for.

Ctrl-click the UIPickerView component and drag from data source to the view controller icon in the bar below the view in storyboard (be sure that you set your custom controller for the view). Do the same for delegate and you're all set.